# Cannot get Spotify to run

Tags: spotify

I installed Spotify successfully but it will not let me log in (error 409).

I tried running `sudo ufw default allow`, but it does not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running the windows version via wine? Or are you using the linux version? (you need premium to be able to use the linux version)

Comment: Or if you are tired of spotify all together, use http://grooveshark.com

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a Spotify Premium account. Perhaps you have installed the Linux preview client? It only supports Premium users. If you don't have a Premium account and don't want one, then you'll need to install wine and run the Windows version.

Comment: I just installed Spotify for **Linux** a few hours ago on an old machine running Lubuntu 13.04. It works fine on my free account. `https://www.spotify.com/us/download/previews/`

Comment: Yes, it works now and has for a while. In 2011, we needed premium accounts to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes download spotify, then go to wine and browse C:/ drive for spotify (under downloads) and right click, open with wine windows program loader

Comment: That only works for Windows, no?

Comment: Download the Linux version at  `https://www.spotify.com/us/download/previews/`. Wine is a last resort when there's no Linux native program to do what you need to do.